# I am not able to create/reindex a unique index in a table

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.1, index-tuning, postgis

I have a table that contains user locations (called public.user_location) and is the following:

```
   Column        |           Type           |                            Modifiers
     id          | bigint                   | not null default nextval('user_location_id_seq'::regclass)
     user_id     | integer                  | not null
     location    | geography(Point,4326)    | 
     accuracy    | smallint                 | 
     datetime    | timestamp with time zone | default now()
Indexes:
   "users_locations_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
   "user_location_datetime_desc_idx" btree (datetime DESC)
   "user_location_user_id_idx" btree (user_id)
   "users_locations_gix" gist (location)

Foreign-key constraints:
   "users_locations_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES "user"(id) ON DELETE 
CASCADE
Referenced by: ...
```

I had a unique constraint composed by the fields `(location, datetime, user_id)`, but then I found out that it was corrupted and so there were duplicates.

After the deletion of the duplicates I tried to reindex but I have got the following message:

```
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
!>
```

So I am not able anymore to create the constraint or even just the unique index and I always got an INVALID index.

What should I do?
Let me know if you need more info.

Cheers

Comment: Before you do *anything* else, read and act on this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Comment: OK, done making a fresh backup? Now go look at the PostgreSQL log files after your "connection to the server was lost" error. There should be a bunch more detail about what happened. It might be quite big, so put it on gist.github.com or pastebin or something rather than pasting it here if it's big. Then comment here when you've uploaded the log.

Comment: X-posted to SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922810/i-am-not-able-to-create-a-unique-index-after-the-deletion-of-duplicates-postgres

Comment: Sorry @ErwinBrandstetter, I have deleted the post on StackOverflow.